# How to access parameter list from application-level middlewares in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, middleware

## **How to access the params in every incoming requests?**

I got a middleware dedicated to checking if the record with recordId existed in my MongoDB database.
Now I wish every single request to go through this middleware with the inspiration from **DRY**. So I created an application-level middleware:
`app.use(checkRecordsExistence)`

The middleware checkRecordsExistence needs to access all param list in order to check the existence of relevant records and store them in `req` object for further use.

However **req.params** always returns {}. What is the way forward? I don't want to add it in the router-level middlewares, because it is not clean, I worship DRY.

Here is my detailed implementation.

```
const checkRecordsExistence = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { params } = req;
    for (const key in params) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(params, key)) {
            // Only check params corresponding to Object Id
            if (key.endsWith('Id')) {
                // Remove the "Id" suffix from the param name
                const modelNameLower = key.slice(0, -2);
                const modelName = modelNameLower.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + modelNameLower.slice(1);

                const Model = mongoose.model(modelName);
                const recordId = params[key];
                const record = await Model.findById(recordId);
                if (!record) {
                    return next(new ErrorResponse(
                        new Error(message.notFound(modelName)),
                        404
                    ));
                }
                // Attach the found record to the request object for further use
                // <=> req._class = await Class.findById(classId)
                req[`_${modelNameLower}`] = record;
                console.log(typeof(record));
            }
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

I can get it going well by putting the middleware in every single router-level route. But it is not clean.

Comment: I think you are overexercising "DRY" here. Not every route even has such a parameter, and not every route needs it checked, and only the route knows which parameter(s) should be checked (and with which model). Trying to make a generic catch-all middleware for this violates the SRP.

Answer (score 1):

express builds the `req.params` in steps according to the path provided to it.
When you use a middleware on the root app (`app.use(...)`) middleware is unaware of the `:param` that is set downstream.

Example:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// use middleware before all routes
app.use(printParamsMiddleware)

// use middleware before a specific routes
//                              |
//                              v
app.get('/users/:userId', printParamsMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.send('in GET /user/:userId')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

function printParamsMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log('print params', req.params)
    next()
}
```

```bash
curl localhost:3000/users/1234
```

output

```
Example app listening on port 3000
print params {}
print params { userId: '1234' }
```

From the example you can see that the `req.params` is set after its passes through a route with a declared path.

---

### Solution Suggestion

I suggest you create a middleware factory that generates a custom middleware per resource

```js
// buildCheckRecordsExistence.middleware.js
function buildCheckRecordsExistence(modelName, paramKey) {
    return async function printParamsMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        const Model = mongoose.model(modelName);
        const recordId = req.params[paramKey];

        const record = await Model.findById(recordId);
        if (!record) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(
                new Error(message.notFound(modelName)),
                404
            ));
        }
        req[paramKey] = record;
        next();
    }
}
```

```js
// users.controller.js

// create a check records middleware specific for Users
const usersCheckRecordsExistence = buildCheckRecordsExistence('Users', 'userId')

app.get('/users/:userId', usersCheckRecordsExistence, (req, res) => {
    const record = req['userId']
    res.send('in GET /users/:userId', record)
})

app.put('/users/:userId', usersCheckRecordsExistence, (req, res) => {
    const record = req['userId']
    res.send('in PUT /users/:userId', record)
})

app.delete('/users/:userId', usersCheckRecordsExistence, (req, res) => {
    const record = req['userId']
    res.send('in DELETE /users/:userId', record)
})

// no need to use check record here
app.post('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    res.send('in POST /users/:userId')
})

// no need to use check record here
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    res.send('in GET /users')
})
```

The key in this solutions is that you have a reusable code and you can select where to use it.

and in case of multiple resources you can append an additional middleware like so.

```js
const usersCheckRecordsExistence = buildCheckRecordsExistence('Users', 'userId')
const projectsCheckRecordsExistence = buildCheckRecordsExistence('Projects', 'projectId')

app.get('/users/:userId/projects/:projectId', usersCheckRecordsExistence, projectsCheckRecordsExistence, (req, res) => {
   
})
```

Comment: Yeah I guess there is no way to access parameter list inside application-level middlewares. Yours should be the optimal approach.